# I am coding a App that adds Values (Strings) to the Registry in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, types, registry

I am programming a App that adds Strings to the Registry to add custom URLs and Programs/ShortCuts to the context menu. I'm stuck at this point because it doesn't let me write a string to the registry and says some weird error.

Here is a photo (sorry for some things in German :D ):

[image: Error]

And here is the text what is missing / cut on the photo:

[image: Error2]

I tried it with this code:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings")
            My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings\command")
            My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.SetValue("Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings", "(Default)", "@shell32.dll,-4161")
            My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.SetValue("Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings", "icon", "Control.exe")
            My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.SetValue("Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings", "Position", "Middle")
            My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.SetValue("Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings\command", "(Default)", "Control.exe")
```

*I think it comes because it tries to write it as a integer and i try to wrtie a string, but i dont know how to use a String as a type.*

Here is the full code: Form1: http://txt.do/drqp1
                       Form2: txt.do/drqpt

[SOLVED] Availible on GitHub: https://github.com/amir00t/LvL-up

Comment: I think this should be tagged with vb.net, not vba.

Comment: You should include the exception and its stack trace in the post, not just a screenshot of it.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean because im new with programming

Comment: I added the entire Code for the two Forms

Comment: You are getting an UnauthorizedAccessException.  Writing to HKCR probably requires admin rights (i.e. you need to "Run as administrator" - or whatever that is in German).  To debug, you may need to run Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled Exception when trying to add registry key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404463/unhandled-exception-when-trying-to-add-registry-key)

Comment: i tried to build it and run it outside as a Admin and it spit out another error that basically said that it couldn't convert "@shell32.dll" to an integer

Comment: and no i have a different problem because it tries to write it as an integer and doesnt work on my pc aswell @Visual Vincent

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `UnauthorizedAccessException` see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404463/unhandled-exception-when-trying-to-add-registry-key).

For your second problem: You're using the [**`SetValue()` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345(v=vs.110).aspx) incorrectly, you ought to check IntelliSense when writing the code.

- The first parameter is the name of the value.
- The second parameter is the value to store in the registry.
- The third parameter is an enumeration value (of type `Integer`) indicating what kind of data you're entering in the registry.

The correct use is:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("<relative\sub\keys>", True).SetValue("<value name>", "<value>")

'For instance:
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("DesktopBackground\Shell\Settings", True).SetValue("(Default)", "@shell32.dll,-4161")
```

Comment: @Max if it helped, consider accepting. Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: im changing the code then im doing it :DD (I know its the checkmark ;D )

Comment: still spits errors out idk why (its a different error putting the new code and pics in the question)

Comment: heres the new code and the new error message                   
 Form1 v2: http://txt.do/drqe6
 Form2 v2:http://txt.do/drqej
 Error (the new one): http://txt.do/drqe4
the custom url doenst spit errors out but it doesnt do the task because the Variables dont get added

Comment: @Max : That's a difference question, the answer can be found in: [**What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) Presumably the `BoM` variable is null, but without knowing the exact line I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: it is in Form1 in line 7 to 14 because it needs to check the Position the user wants i gave it string in the part too

Comment: @Max : I can't see line numbers on my phone. Either way you have to make sure `BoM` isn't null. The answers in the post I linked to contain good information on how to find the cause of an NRE. -- You can inspect variables when the exception is thrown via the `Autos` window (can be opened via menu `Debug > Windows > Autos`).

Comment: oh sorry but i dont have this tool in vs

Comment: You should? Are you using VS Express? Otherwise there's also the `Locals` window (`Debug > Windows > Locals`). It should exist in any VS version. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290840(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i have none of these both EDIT: oh i need to be in debug mode sorry

Comment: @Max : That's why you do it _**"when the exception is thrown"**_. ;)

Comment: i got it i defined a start parameter for the Position Variable if it is detected you'll get a messagebox thank you im trying the custom one now

Comment: the custom one doesnt work i tried to do it like this *My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("DesktopBackground\Shell\" + givenName, True).SetValue("(Default)", "@shell32.dll")*

It doesnt recognize the variable and creates everthing without it

Comment: What is this `givenName`? Also, you can do `ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked Then` instead of making an entire new `If`-statement.

Comment: it should be able to add a custom chosen url in a batch script (which i have done) which the context menu refers to but the varialbe that lets you choose the name of the registry key and the batch script doesnt get added where i tried to add it (in the code lines which need the variable) I tried it like this : *My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("DesktopBackground\Shell\" + givenName, True).SetValue("(Default)", "@shell32.dll")*

Comment: @Max : You're just asking more and more here... Not that I don't want to help you, but it's very hard to do so without a proper perspective. If my answer solved your initial problem please accept it. If you need more help then you should rather ask a new question where you can provide code, screenshots, examples, etc. properly (do provide examples of what values your variables have got).

Comment: @Max : You can place a breakpoint in the code to stop execution at a specific line in order to inspect variables. Step-through debugging using breakpoints is a very efficient way of finding out the problem yourself. Here's some info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: i  posted the second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543526/variables-cant-get-embedded