# Can't create registry key/subkey VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have some code causing me trouble, it's worked until now and I can't think of anything I've changed that will have affected it (including Windows settings and code).

The code is as follows:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\EastSoft\Checkout2017")
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.SetValue("SOFTWARE\EastSoft\Checkout2017", "AcceptedEULA", "True")
```

As I said, it used to work fine, but now I am greeted with the message:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\EastSoft\Checkout2017' is denied.'

I am using Windows 10 Pro (64 Bit) running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks guys!

James

Comment: Is it possible that you had been running it RUNAS Administrator, and aren't now?

Comment: The code needs to be running as administrator to write to HKLM\SOFTWARE.  How are you running the code?  If debugging, start VS2017 using "Run as administrator".

Comment: The program is not running with correct privs, try to run as administrator.

Comment: That's worked, thank you. Any reason why this has changed on my system?

Comment: I don't know the reason to why it was working before but not any longer, but using my following answer you can force your app to always run with administrator privileges: [Unhandled Exception when trying to add registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404463/unhandled-exception-when-trying-to-add-registry-key)